# python asyncio coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I am using python 3.8 with this code

```
async def main():
    pass

async def build():
    pass

asyncio.create_task(build())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.create_task(main())
pending = asyncio.all_tasks()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*pending))
```

and get the following error

> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'build' was never awaited

What am I missing here? shouldn't run until complete wait for all the tasks to finish?

Comment: Are you getting other exceptions before that warning? If so, you should include them in the question. For example, when I run your code under Python 3.7, I get a "no running event loop" exception in the call to `asyncio.create_task(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As the loop is not running when creating the task, `asyncio` is unable to attach tasks to it.

This can be fixed by replacing `asyncio.create_task()` with `loop.create_task()`.

The full error can be retrieved using `asyncio.gather(..., return_exceptions=True)` so `gather()` will raise a `RuntimeError: no running event loop`.